# Composite Key in MS Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Question 1:
And how to create two fields as primary keys(Attribute A is primary key
and Attribute B is primary key)

Question 2:
How to create composite key(Attribute A and B together as primary key)

In MS Access 2003.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select both fields, hold the shift key and then right click and choice primary key. This will make both keys primary key. Meaning the combination must always be unique, and I guess this should answer both questions.

Comment: Thank you, but this is the answer for my 2nd question. But My first question is like, a table has two different primary keys (not the combination of the two keys)

Comment: It is impossible for a table to have two primary keys -- while there can be two candidate keys, there can only actually be one real PK.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can't create 2 primary keys, you can set the indexed setting to `Yes` (No Duplicates), this will prevent 2 entries the same being entered and also provide faster searching.